# What is occurring when solving for $x$ in $Ax = V$ graphically?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to reason with myself what is occurring in the multiplication of a matrix $A$, by some vector $x$, to arrive at vector $v$. I believe I am not understanding what the matrix graphically represents.

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 ,4 \\ 3, 5 \\\end{bmatrix}$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 2 ,4 \\ 3, 5 \\\end{bmatrix}x = \begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$.

I've set up the above arbitrary matrix $A$, which results in the vector $x = \begin{bmatrix} -9 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}$.

I am graphing the equations in the matrix as two linear equations, and am showing the solution as indicated:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/octl7.png)

My understanding now is to say that the matrix $A$ multiplied by the vector $x$ results in the vector $v$. I'm not understanding where the actual multiplication fits into the graph. Are the lines manipulated by the vector x to reach $v$? I understand how vectors are multiplied together, but are lines and vectors done somehow in the same manner? Is there a different way that matrices are actually graphed? I trust I have some fundamental flaw in the graphing of the linear equations here that is throwing me off. It is probably a trivial question but one I would like to understand to get a better feel for what is occurring.

Comment: I suggest using MathJax and also expressing $x$ as a column vector to make things more straightforward.

Comment: How did you get the vector $(26, \ 15)$? When I calculate using your matrix I get a vector of $(\frac{29}{4}, \ -\frac{15}{4})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding now is to say that the matrix $A$ multiplied by the vector $x$ results in the vector $v$.

That is what's happening.

> I'm not understanding where the actual multiplication fits into the graph.

Not sure what this means.

> I understand how vectors are multiplied together

Be careful, there is no vector-by-vector multiplication here.

> Is there a different way that matrices are actually graphed?

Matrices, when considered as a box of numbers, aren't usually graphed. But if you consider each column (or less commonly, each row) of the matrix is a vector, then you can draw vectors from the origin to the point shown by the matrix columns. This all works in 1D, 2D and 3D only.

When you multiply a matrix $M$ by some column vector $x$ and get the resulting vector $v$, $v$ is a linear combination of the *columns* of $M$. For example, say
$M =\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{bmatrix} -9 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}$ then:

$$
Mx = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} -9 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix} =
(-9) \times \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} + 
6 \times \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Very sorry for throwing the initial matrix up there, I edited to make the question make sense. That being said your answer did help to clarify some of of my confusion.  I was getting confused with graphing of the line from the matrix (i.e. 2x + 2y = 29/4) and the vector [2; 3]

Comment: No worries, I updated my answer. Glad I could help.